# Mouse position issues in XNA 3.1

Tags: xna, mouseevent

I am using XNA 3.1 for the a game development, I am having little issue with the mouse position, I am also providing the screen shots of the issue, for now in the code below I am trying to display text "Start" exactly at mouse Position but the location of the the text is around 200 - 250 pixels away from the cursor instead to be at the same point where the cursor is on game window.

```
void MenuMainMenuDraw()
        {
            // Main Menu After Draw
            // Menu Option After Draw

            MouseState ms = Mouse.GetState();

            spriteBatch.DrawString(fontMenu, "Start"
               , new Vector2(ms.X, ms.Y)
               , Color.Red);


            spriteBatch.DrawString(fontMenu, "Options"
                , new Vector2((float)MENU_GLOBAL.MENU_POSITION_X, (float)MENU_GLOBAL.OPTION_POSITION_Y)
                , Color.Red);

            spriteBatch.DrawString(fontMenu, "Leader's Board"
                , new Vector2((float)MENU_GLOBAL.MENU_POSITION_X, (float)MENU_GLOBAL.HIGHSCORE_POSITION_Y)
                , Color.Red);

        }
```

[image]
Regards
MGD

Comment: What's fontMenu look like? Does `Mouse.GetState()` return the mouse coords in screen space or window space?

Comment: I am not sure in which reference it is giving me the coordinates because even if i get the mouse to the 0,0 position of the screen (Left Corner) still it gives Y in minus like around -300

Comment: @asawyer GetState() returns a value relative to the game window.

Comment: do you call the draw method in some kind of while(true) loop or just one time? It may be a stupid comment but if you don't redraw your XNA application all the time, items wont move..

Answer (score 2):

There are a few possible causes that I can think of. I can't see anything directly wrong with the code snippet that you posted, so if none of these things resolve it, post more of your code.

Does the same problem occur when you create a new `SpriteFont` using the default font face? It may be a problem with the spacing in the font you're currently using.

In your `spriteBatch.Begin(...)` code are you supplying a transformMatrix? If so, try just using `spriteBatch.Begin()` with no arguments. Are you doing anything unusual like applying an `Effect`s to your SpriteBatch drawing?

Are you drawing to a render target that is then redrawn to the screen?

Comment: no, I am not using any thing special i mean i am just drawing in the normal way, I dunno why i am having this problem

Comment: Did you try it with a different sprite font? Otherwise, like I said, edit your post and add more code. It's pretty hard to figure out what's going on with so little information.

Answer (score 0):

I've had mouse position issues that seemed strange if my game window was actually larger than the resolution of the computer screen that I was running the game on. Its a quick check but it just might help. (Also remember that XNA draws images from the center point, but I believe by default draws test from the text's upper left corner). Hope that helps